# Error in nls - number of iterations exceeded maximum

Tags: r, initialization, curve-fitting

I am having an issue when trying to fit my data.
This is the data:

```
x = c(1, 1.071519305, 1.148153621, 1.230268771, 1.318256739, 1.412537545, 1.513561248, 1.621810097, 1.737800829, 1.862087137, 1.995262315, 2.13796209, 2.290867653, 2.454708916, 2.630267992, 2.818382931, 3.01995172, 3.235936569, 3.467368505, 3.715352291, 3.981071706, 4.265795188, 4.570881896, 4.897788194, 5.248074602, 5.623413252, 6.025595861, 6.45654229, 6.918309709, 7.413102413, 7.943282347, 8.511380382, 9.120108394, 9.77237221, 10.47128548, 11.22018454,    12.02264435, 12.88249552, 13.80384265, 14.79108388, 15.84893192, 16.98243652, 18.19700859, 19.498446, 20.89296131, 22.38721139, 23.98832919, 25.70395783, 27.54228703, 29.51209227, 31.6227766, 33.88441561, 36.30780548, 38.9045145, 41.68693835, 44.66835922, 47.86300923, 51.2861384, 54.95408739, 58.88436554, 63.09573445, 67.60829754, 72.44359601, 77.62471166, 83.17637711, 89.12509381,    95.4992586, 102.3292992, 109.6478196, 117.4897555, 125.8925412, 134.8962883, 144.5439771, 154.8816619, 165.9586907, 177.827941, 190.5460718, 204.1737945, 218.7761624, 234.4228815, 251.1886432, 269.1534804, 288.4031503, 309.0295433, 331.1311215, 354.8133892, 380.1893963, 407.3802778, 436.5158322, 467.7351413, 501.1872336, 537.0317964, 575.4399373, 616.5950019, 660.693448, 707.9457844, 758.577575, 812.8305162, 870.96359, 933.2543008, 1000)

y = c(0, 39.42531967, 81.67031097, 126.9366341, 179.8504534, 237.9146471, 300.9332733, 373.9994125, 452.2911911, 544.5717812, 644.4305916,757.5670443, 880.1954813, 1015.045167, 1160.563695, 1316.477197, 1483.424418, 1668.380672, 1869.099593, 2083.298305, 2308.72922, 2552.533248, 2806.782363, 3074.749213, 3354.913032, 3653.567198, 3961.982443, 4285.416754, 4625.505185, 4974.839962, 5329.418374, 5696.722268, 6069.748689, 6447.903256, 6826.334958, 7218.057591, 7607.64304, 8005.992733, 8403.318251, 8798.355661, 9201.456877, 9613.1821, 10022.47749, 10430.83497, 10841.5067, 11256.68048, 11675.94707, 12085.72448, 12500.17168, 12905.54582, 13311.92593, 13707.0245, 14089.76524, 14459.48122, 14813.21421, 15145.30591, 15459.10593, 15752.7922, 16023.09928, 16269.888, 16493.69043, 16693.68774, 16869.79643, 17021.69506, 17154.34004, 17264.76423, 17355.82129, 17427.48725, 17486.7706, 17530.49824, 17563.61638, 17588.39795, 17605.32753, 17617.36935, 17624.3971, 17629.48694, 17632.2512, 17633.91595, 17634.67971, 17635.11862, 17635.35591, 17635.4941, 17635.61014, 17635.64404, 17635.66099, 17635.67794, 17635.67794, 17635.67794, 17635.67794, 17635.67794, 17635.67794, 17635.67794, 17635.67794, 17635.67794, 17635.67794, 17635.67794, 17635.67794, 17635.67794, 17635.67794, 17635.67794, 17635.67794)
```

## EDIT

Number of iterations increased untill 1000.

This is the code I used with the equation that has physical meaning when interpreting the results of the coefficients:

```
# tanh function definition:
ftanh = function(x, x0, a, b, k) {
  (1/2) * a * (1 + (tanh(k*(x-x0)))) + b
}

# Fitting code using nonlinear least square:
nlc <- nls.control(maxiter = 1000)
fitmodel <- nls(y ~ ftanh(x, x0, a, b, k), control=nlc, start=list(x0 = 7, a = -29500, b = 17500, k = -0.032))

# Plotting fitted cumulative function

options(scipen = 10) 

plot(x, predict(fitmodel), type="l", log = "x", col="blue", xlab = "x", ylab = "y")

points(x, y, col = "red")

legend("topleft", inset = .05, legend = c("exp","fit"),
       lty = c(NA,1), col = c("red", "blue"), pch = c(1,NA), lwd = 1, bty = "n")

summary(fitmodel)
```

This is the best fit I got using Excel just by guessing the initial values (orange line):

[image: Excel Plot]

I am assuming that my initial values are not the best, but I am in a constant loop and it seems like there is no way out. I am pretty sure that ***b*** value is okay, and that ***x0*** and ***a*** are around my initial values, but ***k*** is actually determining the steepness. Any idea?

Comment: You could use `control = nls.control(maxiter = 1000)` in your nls function to increase the number of iterations of the nls function.

Comment: @Consistency Yep, I tried that. It leads me to an error _Error in nls(y ~ ftanh(x, x0, a, b, k), control = nlc, start = list(x0 = 7,  : step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562_. So it is the inital values issue.

Comment: Reparameterize to alpha0 + alpha1 * tanh(...) and use algorithm = "plinear". See the documentation examples for how to use it. That way you only need starting values for the two non-linear parameters.

Comment: your 7th `x` value is missing a `1.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your fit function does not describe your data. In the logarithmic plot it looks OK but is is actually more like a simple `tanh`. As the bending differs from `tanh` an even better model is of type `a tanh(b*(x-c)**d)**(1/d)`

Not using r but simple python it looks like:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit 


def func1(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.tanh(b*(x-c)) 

def func2(x, a, b, c,d):
    return a*np.tanh(b*np.fabs((x-c))**d)**(1/d) 


initialGuess1=[y[-1], 1, 0]
initialGuess2=[y[-1], 1, 0,1]

popt1,pcov1 = curve_fit(func1, x, y,initialGuess1)
popt2,pcov2 = curve_fit(func2, x, y,initialGuess2)

print popt1
print popt2

fittedData1=[func1(s, *popt1) for s in x]
fittedData2=[func2(s, *popt2) for s in x]

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.plot(x,fittedData1)
ax.plot(x,fittedData2)
ax.set_xscale('log')

plt.show()

>> [  1.74207552e+04   3.53554258e-02   2.20477585e-01]
>> [  1.76893061e+04   1.90416542e-01   1.19819247e+00   5.59529032e-01]
```

[image: fit]
Data in blue, `tanh`fit in orange and modified fit function in green.

Initial guesses are straight forward. (You could play around a bit to get rid of the kink near zero)

Comment: I have to agree that this equation doesn't describe my data well, as you have mentioned. The reason is that this equation is good for normal Gaussian distribution which you would translate into cumulative. In this case, my original data doesn't follow Gaussian distribution so your fitting equation suggestion is adding value. @mikuszefski

Comment: can you just add to your answer the fitting values of the coefficients you used in your formula?

Comment: @numb added the output. Concerning the Gaussian distribution you could use the error function i.e. `erf`. Anyhow, either your error is single sided or the integral is weird as your data basically starts linear from approx zero. It does not have the long flat tail of neither `erf` or `tanh` unless you drop negative values, hence , single sided. (btw, all better seen in linear scale)

Comment: thanks for the idea, I will apply it in r and check it in linear scale.

Comment: @numb Did you look at the derivative of your data. If that's the distribution function, it is sort of strange. It reminded me first of a Poisson distribution, but it is not. For large values (x>100) it is well fitted by exp(- ax)----I mean extremely well---for intermediate values (10<x <100) 1/sqrt(x^2+b) or even  1/x are quite OK. Or even better, for 0<x<100 (a+x)/(b+x^2) is very good.

Comment: Yes, I know it looks strange but it is unweighted distribution coming from direct experimental measurement. The square weighted distribution gives the normal distribution. If I use Weibull 3 parameter equation, the fitting is perfect in all ranges. 
But I haven't check the derivatives of my data. Will do it!

Comment: @numb OK, not knowing neither your experiment nor your data, it is hard to tell.  I only see that the Weibull is of type exp(-x) if beta=1, but it is unlikely to fit the derivative of your data.

Comment: I used this Weibull eq: `f(x) = 0 + (d-0)\exp(-\exp(b(\log(x)-e)))`. Anyway, I'll make a library of all equations with RSE for the fitting. Thanks for the insight.